# If $a \equiv b\mod n$ then what is $a^m \mod n$ in terms of $a,b,n,m$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If $a \equiv b\mod n$ then $a^m \equiv x \mod n$. Please express $x$ in terms of $a,b,n,m$.
Also please provide an explanation, if possible.

Comment: You already wrote the answer: $x\equiv a^m\equiv b^m\mod n$.

Comment: actually the question was to find the remainder when 3^51 is divided by 7
so 3^3 = -1(mod 7)
Now by taking power 17 on both sides.. 
What will happen to remainder?

Comment: If $a\equiv b\mod n$, it follows for any $m\in \mathbb N$ that $a^m\equiv b^m\mod n$.

Comment: Does your notation $\ a\equiv b\ {\rm mod}\ n\ $ mean that $b$ is the remainder of $a$ divided by $n$, or does it denote a congruence, i.e. $\,n\mid a-b\,?\ \ $

Comment: @Bill 
the notation means that a-b is divisible by n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to work with *congruences* rather than remainder (or mod) *operations*. Recall that $\,a\equiv b\pmod n\,$ means precisely that $\,n\mid a-b.\,$ Then we have an *arithmetic* of congruences highly analogous to ordinary integer arithmetic - see the fundamental rules below.

Let's consider your real question (in comments). Working mod $7$, by the $\rm\color{#0a0}{Power\ Rule\ (PR)}$ 
 $$\,\color{#c00}{3^3\equiv -1}\,\overset{\large\rm\color{#0a0}{(PR)}}\Rightarrow\,  (\color{#c00}{3^3})^{17}\equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})^{17}\,\Rightarrow\, 3^{51}\equiv -1\pmod 7$$

Therefore $\ 3^{51} = -1 + 7k,\ $ so $\, -1\equiv 6\,$  is the remainder left when $\,3^{51}$ is divided by  $\,7$.

---

**Congruence Sum Rule** $\rm\qquad\quad  A\equiv a,\quad B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c0f}{A+B\,\equiv\, a+b}\ \ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\: |\: A\!-\!a,\ B\!-\!b\ \Rightarrow\ m\ |\ (A\!-\!a) + (B\!-\!b)\ =\ \color{#c0f}{A+B - (a+b)} $

**Congruence Product Rule** $\rm\quad\ A\equiv a,\ \ and \ \  B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ \color{blue}{AB\equiv ab}\ \ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\: |\: A\!-\!a,\ B\!-\!b\ \Rightarrow\ m\ |\ (A\!-\!a)\ B + a\ (B\!-\!b)\ =\ \color{blue}{AB - ab} $

**Congruence** $\,\rm\color{#0a0}{Power\ Rule}$ $\rm\qquad\ \, \color{}{A\equiv a}\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}{A^n\equiv a^n}\ \  (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\ $ It is true for $\rm\,n=1\,$ and $\rm\,A\equiv a,\ A^n\equiv a^n \Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{A^{n+1}\equiv a^{n+1}},\,$ by the Product Rule, so the result follows by induction on $\,n.$

**Polynomial Congruence Rule** $\ $ If $\,f(x)\,$ is polynomial with *integer* coefficients then  $\ A\equiv a\ \Rightarrow\ f(A)\equiv f(a)\,\pmod m.$

**Proof** $\ $ By induction on $\, n = $ degree $f.\,$ Clear if $\, n = 0.\,$ Else $\,f(x) = f(0) + x\,g(x)\,$ for $\,g(x)\,$ a polynomial with integer coefficients of degree $< n.\,$  By induction $\,g(A)\equiv g(a)\,$ so $\, A g(A)\equiv a g(A)\,$ by the Product Rule. Hence $\,f(A) = f(0)+Ag(A)\equiv f(0)+ag(a) = f(a)\,$ by the Sum Rule.

**Beware** $ $ that such rules need not hold true for other operations, e.g.
the exponential analog of above $\rm A^B\equiv a^b$ is not generally true (unless $\rm B = b,\,$ so it reduces to the Power Rule, so follows by inductively applying $\,\rm b\,$ times the Product Rule).

Comment: WoW! I like your color! :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say $S = (|a-b|\,/\,n \times m\,/\,n )$.
Then $x = (S-\lfloor S \rfloor)\times n; x \in \{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$

Explanation: 
$r = |a-b|\,/n$ is a remainder of $a$ divided by $n$ (whole positive number).
$r\times m$ is the accumulated remainder of $a^m$.
$S = r\times m\,/n$ is a fraction whose decimal part represents $x/n$. So $x/n = S-\lfloor S \rfloor$ where $\lfloor S \rfloor$ stands for $floor(S)$.